# Induced Matrix Norm Property Help

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am trying to see how my textbook went from saying:

$\max_{x \neq 0} ||A(x/||x||)|| = \max_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$.

But I am having some trouble seeing this. (Here, $A$ is a matrix, and $x$ is a vector).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the quantity $$||A\cdot {x\over ||x||}||$$ is invariant w.r.t. the magnitude of $x$, since for all $k\ne 0$ $$||A\cdot {kx\over ||kx||}||{=||A\cdot {x\over ||x||}||\\=||A\cdot {kx\over k||x||}||\\=||A\cdot {x\over ||x||}||}$$

Comment: Hi @Mostafa Ayaz. Thanks for this. But, I am still not seeing the property as proven/given in the original question

Comment: Well, because of the invariance, you can draw out the norm-1 vectors (i.e. $x$ with $||x||=1$) and perform the maximization over them since $$||A\cdot {x\over ||x||}||=||A\cdot {x\over 1}||=||A\cdot {x}||$$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks Mostafa.

Comment: Good luck!!....